# how to do a conditional pop() on an element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an element, that i need to pop from an array, say:

```
arr = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5]
if (value === 3){
 arr.pop() // so if the value is '3', I'd like to pop that record from the array, and record could be anywhere between, after or before in a list of array.
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```
var ind = arr.indexOf(3);
if(ind != -1) {
  arr.splice(ind, 1);
}
```

Comment: At the minimum, please at least link to the documentation for splice. At this time it's a code-dump and an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create an array without the item(s):

```
arr = arr.filter(function(v){ return v != 3; });
```

This will remove the value even if it occurs more than once in the array.

(Note the compatibility information in the documentation. The `filter` method is not available in all browsers, e.g. IE 8.)